# for文のある特定の位置だけ繰り返される現象を解決したい

Tags: google-apps-script

google formsにて希望調査をとり、自動で分配するプログラムを作成しております。
本来であればaft5の後は何もないので終了するはずなのですが、急にaft:1が割り込んできてしまいます。仮に、for文が回り続けているのであれば、bef:1なども出てこないとおかしいかと思います。{}や;のつけ忘れも見当たらないため解決できずに困っております。お力添えいただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

#### プログラム

`k=0, clist.length=6` となっております。

```
以上省略
  for(var a=k;a<clist.length;a++){
    Logger.log("clist:"+clist.length);
    Logger.log("a1:"+a);
    list=[];
    clist=[];
    clist = lmt3(sCount,clist,n);//clist=第n希望までの合計人数
    if(clist[a][1]>limitT){//上限以上の講座検出
      var cl=sCount.getRange(a+1,n).getValue();//講座名
      for(let b=2;b<=sChange.getLastRow();b++){
        if(sChange.getRange(b,n+3).getValue().match(clist[a][0])){//sChange(b,n+3)とclist[a][0]が一致したら
          list.push([b]);//b番目をlistに挿入
        }//if
      }//for
      Logger.log("list");
      Logger.log(list);
    }//if
    Logger.log("bef:"+a);
    m3(n,sCount,clist,limitT,sChange,decision,sForm,countFormR,countFormC,list,p,a,cl,tname);
    Logger.log("aft:"+a);
  }//for
以下省略
```

#### 結果

```
以上省略
2021/11/30 10:51:45 情報  bef:5
-m3開始-
2021/11/30 10:51:45 情報  a:5
2021/11/30 10:51:45 情報  list==
-m3終了-
2021/11/30 10:51:46 情報  aft:5
2021/11/30 10:51:46 情報  aft:1
以下省略
```

Comment: 表示されているスクリプトと、`-結果-`の内容の関係をお教えいただけないでしょうか。また、スクリプトを見ますと、ループ内で`clist`が変化しているようです。この場合、２回目のループからは新しい値の`clist`が使用されます。もしもこのフローが意図していない場合は、これが原因になっている可能性があります。その場合はこの部分を修正するのはいかがでしょうか。また、スクリプトでは、`getValue`がループ内で使われています。このような場合はスクリプトのコストが高くなりますのでご注意ください。[Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: 本来であればもっと長いコードになっているのですが、ここでは受講可能な人数よりも多くなった講座をclist[講座,人数]の中から探し、その講座を受講している人がスプレッドシート上の何番目の人なのかという情報をlistに入れています。そのあとm3というlistに入った人を空いているところに分配し、記述してあるプログラムに再帰しています。また、Logger.log("bef:"+a);　からを実行結果として表示させていただいております。
clistに関しては再帰的にする関係上、1度中身を削除しております。getValueは上限以上の講座を受けている人をlistに挿入するためなのですが、別の方法を検討するべきでしょうか？

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。変数`clist`がループ内で変更されると次のループで新たな`clist`の`clist.length`が使用されることからこのフローは少し難しいかと思い、これを修正することについて提案させていただきました。しかしながら、ご返事からはループ内で変数`clist`を変化させることは意図しているものと理解しました。この場合は少し複雑になるかと思いますので、スクリプトの各行毎にデバッグをしてループ中の各変数を確認しながらスクリプトを改善していくのはいかがでしょうか。`getValue`のループ内での使用について、使用時にスクリプトの速度に問題を感じないようであればそのままでも宜しいのではないかと思われます。データ量が多くなると速度が遅くなることでスクリプトの制限時間に到達する危険性があると思いましたので先のようにコメントしました。この提案について謝罪致します。

Comment: ご提案ありがとうございました。clistおよびgetValueの記述に関しては改善の余地がありそうということなのでその点再度検討させていただきます。今回6人分のデータで作成しておりましたが20倍近くになるため処理速度の改善も視野に入れさせていただきます。ありがとうございます。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。Spreadsheetへのデータのやり取りのポイントは、可能な限り、最初に必要な範囲の全データを取得し、取得したデータをループなどを使って変更し、変更したデータをSpreadsheetへ戻すような流れです。これが低コストのスクリプトに繋がります。例えば、分散したセルを更新する場合は、全体のデータを上書きするのもありですし、Sheets APIを使えばピンポイントで分散したセルを一度のAPIコールで変更可能です。Stackoverflowには様々な状況でのサンプルスクリプトが掲載されていますので参考になるかと思います。

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。一度配列にすべて格納して同様のプログラムを作成していたのですが、そちらでもうまくいかなかったため、今回のように毎度シートに落とし込むやり方をしていました。前回と今回のを組み合わせて適切な位置でシートに落とし込めるよう改良してみたいと思います。
初心者のためsheets APIの存在を知りませんでした。stackoverflowには質問のみで活用させていただいていたので、類似した内容の探し出しも行ってみたいと思います。参考にさせていただきます。ありがとうございます。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。表示されているスクリプトから、Spreadsheetから必要な範囲のデータを全て取得し、そのデータをループ内でIf statementがtrueのときに変更し、ループの後でその更新されたデータをSpreadsheetに戻す流れが使えそうに思いました。この場合、コストも低くなりますので、データが大きくなった場合でもすぐにスクリプトが終了すると思われます。期待したように進まない場合は、サンプルの入力データと欲しい出力データを示されると、多くのユーザが回答を考えるのに役立つと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。今回初めてのコードの質問だったのため、コードも全て記述するわけにもいかず分かりにくい内容となってしまい申し訳ございませんでした。次の制作でもうまくいかなかった場合、ご指摘の通り入力データと出力データを含めて再度質問を投稿させていただきます。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございます。データを表示される際は安全のため、データ内の個人情報を確認してそれらを除去してから表示することをお勧めします。